# bower-rails font-awesome.css not found after resolve

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, asset-pipeline

I am using the rails-bower gem. https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails

I installed font-awesome, my bowerfile looks like this

```
# A sample Bowerfile
# Check out https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails#ruby-dsl-configuration for more options

# asset 'bootstrap'
asset 'bootstrap-sass'
asset 'font-awesome'
asset 'jquery'
asset 'jquery-ujs'
asset 'nicescroll'
```

After doing a bower install my font-awesome works.

When pushing to heroku my stylesheets aren't loaded. This because I have to do a $ rake assets:precompile

The precompilation triggers a **bower:resolve** which causes the font-awesome.css to not be found anymore and my site quits working.

```
couldn't find file '/home/christoph/Documenten/kratos/vendor/assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
  (in /home/christoph/Documenten/kratos/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:14)
```

The font-awesome.css file is located at that directory but it is named font-awesome.css.erb. How can I fix this so that the erb file is referenced when doing an asset precompilation.

This whole thing also blocks me pushing to heroku.

Comment: Why are you not doing the rake on heroku? Heroku supports pre/post install scripts just fine.

Comment: Because precompilation locally does not work why should it work on Heroku? I tried it anyways with no effect.

Comment: hmm, did you search https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails/issues to see if this is a known issue? (and if not, did you file it to get a response from the people who are absolutely better suited to answer it than anyone on Stackoverflow?)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I'll keep my question over here since I do not know if that repo is that activily maintained.